# How to structure and return key value pair from a JSON call with Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete

I am currently using Autocomplete with dynamic inputs, currently my Autocomplete works fine.

I basically need to return 2 values back from `JSON`. One is the `ID` of the song and the other is the `title` of that song. The `ID` is the primary key of that table so it will always be different.

I figure I can do this with a key/value where the `key` is the `ID` and the `value` is the `title`.

When the user clicks on the input field right now it returns both the `ID` and `title` of the song in the field. What I need to be able to do is just put the `title` in the field and be able to send off the `ID` to my `jquery/AJAX` then to my php script.

This is what is being returned so far. I just want the title in the input field but need the ID to send off to php.

[image: autocomplete example]

I am not even sure if I am structuring my JSON call back correctly to be able to do this.

This is what I have so far in order

**JQUERY AUTOCOMPLETE**

```
$(document).on('focus', 'div.form-group-options div.input-group-option:last-child input', function(){
    var sInputGroupHtml = $(this).parent().html();
    var sInputGroupClasses = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    $(this).parent().parent().append('<div class="'+sInputGroupClasses+'">'+sInputGroupHtml+'</div>');
    $('.searchsong').autocomplete({
        source:'../includes/searchaddsong.php',
        minLength:0,
        select: function(event,ui){ <--THIS IS THE SECTION I THINK I NEED TO RETURN THE ID AND TITLE BUT I DONT KNOW HOW TO PLACE JUST THE TITLE INTO THE INPUT FIELD AND NOT THE ID AS WELL
        }
    });
});
$(document).on('click', 'div.form-group-options .input-group-addon-remove', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**searchaddsong.php**

UPDATE: Edited this `searchaddsong.php` I think I figured this out

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$key="a";
$array = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wafilepaths WHERE title LIKE '%{$key}%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[] = array(
        $row['ID'] => $row['title']
    );
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control searchsong" name="searchsong[]" id="searchsong" type="text" placeholder="Type Something" />
```

**AJAX**

```
$(".loginFormAddSetlist").submit(function () {
var church_code = $('.church_code').val();
var dayofweek = $('.dayofweek').val();
var datepicker = $('.datepicker').val();
var searchsong = $('.searchsong').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../includes/uploadsetlist.php?",
        data:({church_code: church_code, dayofweek: dayofweek, datepicker: datepicker, searchsong: searchsong}),
        success: function(data) {
            $('div.alert4').fadeIn();
            $('div.alert4').html(data);
            $('div.alert4').delay(5000).fadeOut();
        }
    });
return false;
});
```

**uploadsetlist.php**

```
<?
    $ID = $_GET['ID'];
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access these values from the ui parameter on the select option.

```
$('.searchsong').autocomplete({
    source:'../includes/searchaddsong.php',
    minLength:0,
    select: function(event,ui){ 
        alert(ui.item.label + ": " + ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

A more detailed description of this feature is found [in the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

As a side note, you can also attach more data to the `item` object and access it if you explicitly perform the AJAX request:

```
$('.searchsong').autocomplete({
    source:function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../includes/searchaddsong.php",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            delay: 500,
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Title + " (" + item.Id+ ")",
                        value: item.Id,
                        id: item.Id,
                        title: item.Title,
                        image: item.Image
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength:0,
    select: function(event,ui){ 
        alert("id = " + ui.item.id + "\n" +
              "title = " + ui.item.title + "\n" +
              "image = " + ui.item.image);
    }
});
```

Comment: this is returning the value for both. So the alert is coming back as title:title. The ID is not showing up

Comment: Would this be a proper JSON response to work with that? `{"16":"Song One","4":"Song Two","6":"Song Three","7":"Song Four"}`

Comment: Yes, that is the correct format. I added a relevant link to the documentation that describes the label and value fields.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method [_renderItem](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem). I hope it will help you to implement behaviour which you've described